# How to debug a table failing to load in Navicat, Workbench?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a table that won't load in Navicat. I'm beginning to think it's a serious problem with the table - I've never encountered anything like this before. It just stalls when doing the initial `SELECT` of loading 1000 rows. Table is MyISAM, total rows is around 64k.

Any advice on how to debug this? The other tables in the database seem to load fine.

More detail: I noticed something which may be the culprit. For this query:

```
SELECT * FROM data_warehouse AS dw 
LEFT JOIN serialized AS dws ON dw.dw_id = dws.dw_id 
WHERE (dw.ds_id = 2) ORDER BY dw.dw_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

When this happens, and I do `show processlist`, I see that there is an entry that says "Copying to tmp table". It doesn't go away, but stays there. Command type of 'QUERY'.

Also, I noticed an inconsistency between data types. My `data_warehouse` table has `dw_id` as a `bigint`, while `serialized` has dw_id as `int`. Should I just change `serialized`'s dw_id to match? If I do this will anything break?

Comment: Have you had a try with [CHECK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/check-table.html)?

Comment: Didn't know about that. Trying now.

Comment: If there's a problem with your table, you could try [REPAIR TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/repair-table.html) next.

Comment: It says `Op: check, Msg_type: status, Msg_text ok` for `CHECK TABLE`

Comment: Is there anything interesting in your MySQL server log?

Comment: Your table seems ok, but you could try `CHECK TABLE your_table EXTENDED;`, I cite: *Do a full key lookup for all keys for each row. This ensures that the table is 100% consistent, but takes a long time. Applies only to MyISAM tables and views;*

Comment: Is that failsafe? It's just a check, it doesn't actually modify anything?

Comment: @VMai - made another discovery - the data types for one of the columns isn't consistent across 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved - basically what happened was:

In the server there were other queries which made my query not process / get stalled in the queue. A `LEFT JOIN` between 2 tables happened and the datatype for those 2 tables, `dw_id` was not consistent. One was a `bigint` and the other just `int`. This caused the two queries to try to "copy to tmp table" and then made every query afterwards stall.

I debugged it by doing `show processlist` and did `kill QUERYID`. An index needed to be added to the second table with the inconsistent `dw_id` datatype.